# ASP.NET MVC - Best practices when passing dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, architecture

I have a question, that I tried to Google but honestly, I don't really know how to search or even ask this particular question.

Let's imagine I have the following:

**Controller**

```
        [HttpGet]
        public virtual ActionResult Summary()
        {
            var summaryViewModel = new CheckoutSummaryViewModel()
            {
                Products = ProductViewModel.BuildListFromShoppingCart(GetShoppingCart())
            };
            return View("_Summary", summaryViewModel);
        }
```

**ProductViewModel**

```
    public class ProductViewModel
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public static List<ProdutoCheckoutViewModel> BuildListFromShoppingCart(ShoppingCart shoppingCart, IMappingService mappingService)
        {
            var itemsInCart = new List<ProductViewModel>();
            foreach (var item in shoppingCart.ItemsInCart)
            {
                var itemViewModel = mappingService.Map<Product, ProductViewModel>(item.Product);
                itemViewModel.Quantidade = item.Quantity;
                itemsInCart.Add(itemViewModel);
            }

            return itemsInCart;
        }
    }
```

This is not production code. Is just so I can explain what I mean.

Is this the correct way of doing this?

1. Is there a better way than using *static* for building the list? I really don't want to do it inside the controller.
2. Passing IMappingService to the method does not look right. But maybe I'm just being picky. Is it the best way?

Another case, where I need to pass Session State to a static helper class.

```
        public static Guid GetCheckoutId(HttpSessionStateBase session)
        {
            return (Guid)session["checkoutId"];
        }
```

Or, also, sometimes I need to pass as parameter, to helper methods, my "unifOfWork", since I use the repository pattern.

I've come accross this "problem" a lot and I did not find the best way, yet, to do it.

PS: If any of you has a better title for this question, please tell me so I can update it.

Comment: You probably need to look into Dependency Injection and IoC containers (Inversion of Control) to get the desired functionality.  Normally, you want to shy away from using static because they cannot be unit tested easily.  As for session, I would say the controller should reach into the session and pull out the data you'd need and pass that to the next layer.  That wold be a controller responsibility.

Comment: I use Ninject for the unit of work and mapping service, but I may find the answer in DI. About the session, yes, that makes sense...

Comment: IoC containers, like Ninject, are what DI is all about.  Lets see if I can answer you correctly below with a code example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Controller
If you use DI, it would look something like this:

```
public class CheckoutController 
{
    private readonly ICheckoutService _checkoutService;

    public CheckoutController(ICheckoutService checkoutService) =>
        _checkoutService = checkoutService;

    [HttpGet]
    public virtual ActionResult Summary()
    {
        var shoppingCartData = _checkoutService.GetShoppingCart(Session["..."]);
        // The viewmodel here could be returned by your service or the service
        // would return all required data and the viewmodel simply transforms that Dto into what is needed by the UI

        var summaryViewModel = new CheckoutSummaryViewModel()
        {
            Products = shoppingCartData 
        };
        return View("_Summary", summaryViewModel);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've been studying DI and IoC for some time since you pointed it. Now I get it, and it's really what I was looking for.

Comment: DI and IoC might seem a bit scary at first, but it really is just using some interfaces and telling the application how to create that instance at the top - and now you can unit test your code whenever! :)

Comment: Yes! In the last months I've been getting better at it, and now it does not look that scary anymore. Also I unit test everything easily. Thank you so much for your help.